# Removing db2 timestamp microseconds

Tags: timestamp, db2

I am trying to get timestamp from '1190102092000' string. But I don't want  microseconds. 
TO_DATE(RIGHT('1190102092000', 12),'YYMMDDHH24MISS')

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the original timestamp (timestamp(6)), to, let's say, timestamp(0):

```
call admin_cmd('describe select t original, timestamp(t, 0) t_no_ms from table(values TO_DATE(RIGHT(''1190102092000'', 12), ''YYMMDDHH24MISS'')) t(t)');

SQLTYPE_ID  SQLTYPE    SQLLENGTH SQLNAME_DATA   SQLNAME_LENGTH
----------  ---------  --------- ------------ ---------------- 
       392  TIMESTAMP         26 ORIGINAL                    8
       392  TIMESTAMP         19 T_NO_MS                     7
```

Comment: I can't change  server configurations.

Comment: @AdrianaGeghamyan It's not about changing the server configuration. It's only about casting to a special timestamp data type during run-time. What's your real technical goal behind the `I don't want microseconds` phrase?

Comment: I have column in which date is saved as string, e.g. '1181119121554'. I try to convert it to timestamp without microseconds . Even with timestamp(column, 0) result is 2018-11-19 12:15:54.018011.

Comment: I think DATE_TRUNC should work too, but it is not supported in 9.7 version

Comment: What's the result of the following query, when you run it from the db2 clp? `select timestamp(t, 0) t0, timestamp(t, 3) t3, timestamp(t) t6 from (values TO_DATE('190102092000123456', 'YYMMDDHH24MISSFF6')) t(t)`

Comment: ["2019-01-02 09:20:00.019001", "2019-01-02 09:20:00.123201", "2019-01-02 09:20:00.123456"]

Comment: It's hard to believe, that it's really db2... You even get different fraction of seconds for the same constant... All my db2 versions available (including 9.7 in Oracle compatibility mode ON and OFF) return the following result: `2019-01-02-09.20.00 2019-01-02-09.20.00.123 2019-01-02-09.20.00.123456`. What's your Db2 platform, version and Fix Pack?

Answer (score 0):

Use `TIMESTAMP(your_timestamp,0)`

e.g.

```
values TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('2'||'1190102092000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),0)

1                  
-------------------
2119-01-02-09.20.00

  1 record(s) selected.
```